# Where should I put Upper Formula to work in my formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, images

=IMAGE("https://logo.stocklight.com/NYSE/"&$A$21&"_icon.png";4;80;80)

A21 is TEXT : MAIN

how I use upper for A21 to work with my formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this formula:

```
=image("https://logo.stocklight.com/NYSE/"&upper(A21)&"_icon.png")
```

Comment: Works! Thank you very much!